# Selenium. Filter element in list at locator level

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="aui-header-primary">
    <ul class="aui-nav __skate" style="width: auto;">
      <li>
      <li>
      <li>
      <li>
      <li id="create-menu">
  </ul>
</div>
```

At my page level I'm populating List like this:

```
@FindBy(css = ".aui-header-primary ul li")
public List<WebElement> lstMenuItems;
```

I have to exclude `li id="create-menu"` from my list

Currently I have to write a function with something like:

```
if(!element.getText().equals("Create")){
      //populate list
 }
```

Is there a way to do so at locator level? So I wouldn't have to write additional functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code with `XPath` selector:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='aui-header-primary']/ul/li[not(@id='create-menu')]")
```

Same should works with `CSS` selector:

```
@FindBy(css = ".aui-header-primary ul li:not(#create-menu)")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Can I also exclude empty list items same way? Somehow it populates a lot of empty items, so I still need a function to filter them

Comment: What you mean `empty` item? Item that doesn't contain text?

Comment: Yes, in case of XPATH - it contains 1 WebElement that returns getText() = "" and in case of CSS - 22 empty elements

Comment: Try this `XPath` `"//div[@class='aui-header-primary']/ul/li[not(@id='create-menu') and normalize-space(text())]"`

Comment: Returns 0 elements in that case

Comment: On provided `HTML` there is not elements with child text node. Share `HTML` for element **with** child text node

Comment: Empty items was from <li style="display: none;"> which has more items inside - i missed it before. So now it works like @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='aui-header-primary']/ul/li[not(@id='create-menu') and not(@style='display: none;')]") Thanks